# GroupMember Types of a Public Group

Tags: apex, public-group

How can we get the Type of a Group Member?

Using getSObjectType() on the UserOrGroupId of GroupMember we get the Types - but they are only User or Group.

```
List<GroupMember> members = [ SELECT Id, UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE GroupId IN (SELECT id FROM Group where Id = :groupId) ];


for(GroupMember member: members) {
  System.debug(member.Id.getSObjectType() + '-' + member.UserOrGroupId.getSObjectType());


}
```

[image]

Any help/suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code will look like this:

```
List<GroupMember> members = [ SELECT Id, GroupId, UserOrGroupId 
                            FROM GroupMember 
                            WHERE GroupId IN (SELECT id FROM Group where Id = :groupId) ];

List<Id> ids = new List<Id>();
for(GroupMember member: members) {
   ids.add(member.UserOrGroupId);
}
List<Group> lstGroup = [SELECT Name, RelatedId, Type, Id From Group WHERE Id IN:ids];
```

> **RelatedId** will be the Type of Id. For Groups of type “Role,” the ID of the associated UserRole. The RelatedId field is polymorphic.
>
> and **Type** will display as User, Role, Partner User etc as shown in your picture
>
> *Description*
>   Type of the Group. One of the following values:
>
> Regular—Standard Public Group. When you create() a Group, its type must be Regular, unless a partner portal is enabled for the organization, in which case the type can be Regular or PRMOrganization.
>
> Role—Public Group that includes all of the User records in a particular UserRole.
>
> RoleAndSubordinates—Public Group that includes all of the User records in a particular UserRole and all of the User records in any subordinateUserRole.
>
> Organization—Public Group that includes all of the User records in the organization. This Group is read-only.
>
> Case—Public group of users, members of a queue that can own a Case.
>
> Lead—Public group of users, members of a queue that can own a Lead.
>
> Manager—Public group that includes a user’s direct and indirect managers. This Group is read-only.
>
> ManagerAndSubordinatesInternal—Public Group that includes a user and the user’s direct and indirect reports. This Group is read-only.
>
> PRMOrganization—Public Group that includes all of the partners in an organization that has the partner portal feature enabled.
>
> Queue—Public Group that includes all of the User records that are members of a queue.
>
> Territory—Public Group that includes all of the User records in an organization that has the territory feature enabled.
>
> TerritoryAndSubordinates—Public Group that includes all of the User records in a particular UserRole and all of the User records in any subordinateUserRole.
>
> Collaboration—Chatter group.
>
> Only Regular, Case, and Lead can be used when creating a group. The other values are reserved.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
But the Type of the Group (SOQL) and the Type of the GroupMember (from the image) are not matching? Any idea on that?!!

Comment: can you post a picture of the group and group member and Types which you are trying to display?

Comment: I have verified that query in my dev and it is working

Comment: from SalesForce page: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kmiuzaobc31s08a/Screenshot%202016-10-09%2010.26.35.png?dl=0
from developer console: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kjyrjfkx4raf1tl/Screenshot%202016-10-09%2010.26.59.png?dl=0
Thanks for your time.

Comment: what is your debug statement?

Comment: Editing the answer, so you can understand the difference in UI and SOQL query returned data